# why is my select form does not dropping down?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I want to select customer from the select form or combobox in other term. 
but the problem is the select form is not dropping down, it duplicates according to how many customers are in the table where it is taken from. can you help me understand why this is happening. I'm really troubled about this. I will attach the code and pictures below [This is what when there is only one customer in the customer table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5toF.png) [This my problem, the combobox duplicates into two because there are to customers in the customer table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BFxP.png)

```html
<?php
 include('dbconnect.php');
    include('home.php');
?>
<?php include('session.php'); ?>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/demo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/form-login.css">
    <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dataTables.bootstrap.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
 

 <title>Stock Out</title>
<style>
  
  body
{
  background:url('img/bg.png');
        background-repeat:repeat;
}



  p
      {
        color: black;
        font-family: "TekTon Pro", Georgia, Serif;
      }
      a
      {
        color: black;
        font-family: "TekTon Pro", Georgia, Serif;
      }
       a1
   {
    color: white;
    font-family: "Tekton Pro", Georgia, Serif;
   }


    a:hover{text-decoration:none}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<body>
<center>

<div style="margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px;">
<form action="saveoutstock.php" method="post">
 <table  class="table table-bordered" id="tblContact" style="width:100%; background-color:;">
    <thead style="background-color:white;">
    <th style="text-align:center"><a>CODE</a></th>
    <th style="text-align:left"><a>NAME</a></th>
    <th style="text-align:center"><a>ITEMS LEFT</a></th>
    <th style="text-align:center"><a>PRICE</a></th>
    <th style="text-align:center"><a>CUSTOMER'S NAME</a></th>
    <th style="text-align:center"><a>STOCKS TO BE RELEASED</a></th>
    <th style="text-align:center"><a>AMOUNT TENDERED</a></th>
    <th style="text-align:center"><a>ACTION</a></th>
    </thead>
    <?php

     $res=mysql_query("select * from item order by itemcode asc");
     $itemcode = $_GET['itemcode'];
     while($rowres=mysql_fetch_array($res))
     {  
       echo"<tr style='background-color:#F5F5DC;'>";
       if($itemcode == $rowres['itemcode']){
        echo"<input type='hidden' name='price' value='".$rowres['price']."'></input>";
        echo"<input type='hidden' name='left' value='".$rowres['qty']."'></input>";
       echo"<input type='hidden' name='itemcode' value='".$rowres['itemcode']."'></input>";
       echo"<td style='text-align:center'><a>".$rowres['itemcode']."</a></td>";
       echo"<td style='text-align:left'><a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$rowres['item_abb']."</a></td>";
       echo"<td style='text-align:center'><a>".$rowres['qty']."</a></td>";
       echo"<td style='text-align:left'><a class='icon-usd'></a>";
       echo"<a>".number_format($rowres['price']).".00</a></td>";
       $result2=mysql_query("select*from customer ");
       while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
       echo"<td><select name='cusname' class='field'><option value='".$row['cuscode']."'>".$row['name']."</option></select></td>";
       echo"<td style='text-align:center;'><input type='text' style='font-family:tekton pro; text-align:center;' class='field' name='qty' value=''></input></td>";
       echo"<td style='text-align:center;'><input type='text' style='font-family:tekton pro; text-align:center;' class='field' name='amount' value=''></input></td>";
       echo"<td style='text-align:center;'><button style='padding:4px 10px; font-family:tekton pro;' class='btn btn-success'><span class='icon-save'></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Save&nbsp;&nbsp;</button></td>";
      }
      else{
       echo"<td style='text-align:center'><a>".$rowres['itemcode']."</a></td>";
       echo"<td style='text-align:left'><a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$rowres['item_abb']."</a></td>";
       echo"<td style='text-align:center'><a>".$rowres['qty']."</a></td>";
       echo"<td style='text-align:left'><a class='icon-usd'></a>";
       echo"<a>".number_format($rowres['price']).".00</a></td>";
       echo"<td style='text-align:center'><a></a></td>";
       echo"<td style='text-align:center'><a></a></td>";
       echo"<td style='text-align:center'><a></a></td>";
       echo"<td style='text-align:center;'><a style='padding:4px 10px;' href='outstock.php?itemcode=$rowres[itemcode]' class='btn btn-primary'><span class='icon-signin'></span>&nbsp;Stock Out</button></td>"; 
   } 
       echo"</tr>";
      } 
      
    ?>
 </table>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tblContact').dataTable({
     "iDisplayLength": 10,
      "lengthMenu": [5,10, 25, 50]
  });
  });
 </script>
  </form>
</center>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: You include the select tab inside  your loop. It should come before the loop, with the closing select tab after the loop. Only the option should be inside the loop.

Comment: thank you @SloanThrasher . . my problem is solved. thanks for the quick response

Comment: If it worked, please accept the answer.

Comment: @HermeBaaySuarez glad to see that he provided you with a solution. Consider accepting his answer below, it marks the question as solved ;-) *Welcome to Stack*

Comment: I do not know how to accept the answer. . . can you please tell me how to do it? @SloanThrasher sorry I just joined here today I'm not familiar of everything yet

Comment: @Fred-ii- can you tell how to accept the answer pls. .  I'm new here . thanks in advance

Comment: Next to the answer (on the left) there should be a link to accept the answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: done :D thanks again :) I will try to use mysqli next time because it's mostly suggested. . I hope it is easy to learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you include the **select** tag inside your loop, it repeats so you get multiple drop-downs. Only the options tab should be inside the loop.

```
echo "<a>".number_format($rowres['price']).".00</a></td>";
$result2 = mysql_query("select * from `customer`;");
echo "<td><select name='cusname' class='field'>";
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result2) ) {
    echo "<option value='".$row['cuscode']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";
}
echo "</select></td>";
```

Also, you should convert to using mysqli instead of mysql functions. The latter are obsolete and deprecated, and they are less secure.